# Asp GridView not updating

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, updating, nested-gridview

I am using a nested `GridView`. When I click edit, the items appear for editing in a texbox but the new values are not reflecting in the rowupdating. I tried inspecting it through browser also and even then it is fetching old values.

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GVInvoiceDet" runat="server" Width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableViewState="False"
            HorizontalAlign="Left" BorderStyle="Outset" OnRowCancelingEdit="GVInvoiceDet_RowCancelingEdit"
            OnRowEditing="GVInvoiceDet_RowEditing" OnRowDataBound="GVInvoiceDet_RowDataBound" ShowFooter="True"
            OnRowCommand="GVInvoiceDet_RowCommand" OnRowUpdating="GVInvoiceDet_RowUpdating"
            OnRowDeleting="GVInvoiceDet_RowDeleting" OnRowDeleted="GVInvoiceDet_RowDeleted"
            OnRowUpdated="GVInvoiceDet_RowUpdated" AllowSorting="True" DataSourceID="DSItemGrid" DataKeyNames="invoiceno,itemcd">
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#0000ff" ForeColor="Yellow" />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#FFFFCC" ForeColor="#330099" />
            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#FFFFCC" ForeColor="#330099" />
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#FE9CD5" />

            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <a href="javascript:expandcollapse('div<%# Eval("itemcd") %>', 'one');">
                            <img id="imgdiv<%# Eval("itemcd") %>" alt="Click to show/hide Tax Details <%# Eval("itemcd") %>" border="0" src="Images/plus.png" />
                        </a>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="15px" />
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="10%" HeaderText="Item Code" SortExpression="itemcd">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblItemCode" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("itemcd")%>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtItemCode" Width="90%" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("itemcd")%>' Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtItemCode" Width="90%" runat="server" Text='' Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
      <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="5%" HeaderText="Quantity">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblItemQty" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("quantity")%>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtItemQty" Width="90%" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("quantity") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtItemQty" Width="90%" MaxLength="100" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" HeaderText="Edit" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete" ItemStyle-Width="5%">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="linkDeleteInvoiceItem" CommandName="DeleteItem" runat="server">Delete</asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="linkAddInvoiceItem" CommandName="AddItem" runat="server">Add</asp:LinkButton>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
      </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
       <asp:SqlDataSource ID="DSItemGrid" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:GSTCS %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:GSTCS.ProviderName %>"
            SelectCommand="select invoiceno, dt.itemcd itemcd, mast.itemdesc itemdesc, mast.hsncd hsncd, dt.quantity quantity, 
            mast.unitrate unitrate, dt.unitvalue unitvalue, mast.itempercentage itempercentage   
            from GSTINVOICEDT dt join GSTITEMMASTER mast on (dt.itemcd = mast.itemcd and dt.unitcode = mast.unitcode and dt.projectcode = mast.projectcode) 
            where dt.unitcode = :unitCode and dt.projectCode = :projCode and dt.invoiceno = :invoiceNo order by invoiceno, itemcd"
            UpdateCommand="UPDATE GSTINVOICEDT set  quantity = :quantity ,unitRate =:unitRate, unitValue=:unitValue 
                           WHERE invoiceno = :invoiceno and unitcode= :unitcode and projectcode = :projectcode 
                           and itemcd = :itemcd"
            OnUpdating="DSItemGrid_Updating">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:SessionParameter DefaultValue="05" Name="unitCode" SessionField="unit" />
                <asp:SessionParameter DefaultValue="0501" Name="projCode" SessionField="project" />
                <asp:SessionParameter DefaultValue="INVOICENO" Name="invoiceNo" SessionField="invoiceNo" Type="String" />
            </SelectParameters>
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="itemcd" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="quantity" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="unitRate" Type="Decimal" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="unitValue" Type="Decimal" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="invoiceno" Type="String" />
                <asp:SessionParameter Name="unitcode" SessionField="unit" />
                <asp:SessionParameter Name="projectcode" SessionField="project" />                
            </UpdateParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>

    </div>
```

snapshot of the frontend grid showing new Quantity value 500 
[image: Gridview]

[image: inspect]
Snapshot of the inspect element of browser showing old Quantity value 50.

Partial Code for row updating is also getting old value for quantity

```
 protected void GVInvoiceDet_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {
            GridView temp = (GridView)sender;
            //Get the values stored in the text boxes
            string itemCode = ((TextBox)temp.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtItemCode")).Text;
            string quantity = ((TextBox)temp.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtItemQty")).Text;
            string unitRate = ((TextBox)temp.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtItemUnitRate")).Text;
            string unitValue = ((TextBox)temp.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtItemUnitValue")).Text;    
            string unit = Session["unit"].ToString();
            string proj = Session["project"].ToString();
```

Comment: is your database table being update or not ?

Comment: @M.Y.Mnu No update in the database table. Thats why I tried debugging through.

Comment: then you have to check why not updating value in table first.

Comment: Actually it is not picking the new values in row updating... which will fed to update query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can try this code to update row

```
 protected void GVInvoiceDet_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
 {
    string itemCode= (TextBox)GVInvoiceDet.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtItemCode")).Text;
    string quantity = (TextBox)GVInvoiceDet.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtItemQty")).Text;
    string unitRate = ((TextBox)GVInvoiceDet.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtItemUnitRate")).Text;
    string unitValue = ((TextBox)GVInvoiceDet.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtItemUnitValue")).Text;    
    string unit = Session["unit"].ToString();
    string proj = Session["project"].ToString();
    GVInvoiceDet.EditIndex = -1;
    // call bind grid method here
 }
```

Comment: It worked data is updated now. But I didn't get logic what was wrong in my code.

Comment: i think you use **GridView temp = (GridView)sender;** this.